# Taking Screenshot using KIF2 IOS

Tags: ios, kif-framework, kif

Please help me with a sample code of KIF2 for capture a screenshot on demand, I want to take screenshot in simulator using KIF2

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't have time to write and test example code, but KIF provides a method called [`-writeScreenshotForLine:inFile:description:error:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/KIF/3.0.4/Categories/UIApplication+KIFAdditions.html#//api/name/writeScreenshotForLine:inFile:description:error:) in a category on UIApplication that should do what you want. Provided you've set the `KIF_SCREENSHOTS` environment variable as required by the docs, you should be able to call this method directly on the shared application object, something like:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSError *error = nil;
[app writeScreenshotForLine:__LINE__ 
                     inFile:__FILE__
                description:@"your description here" 
                      error:&error];
```

There's also a similar method, `-[KIFSystemTestActor captureScreenshotWithDescription:]` that calls the `UIApplication` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this piece of code is not working and I am not looking for this

Comment: What *are* you looking for? What have you tried, and why has that not worked?

Comment: I tried using this KIFSystemTestActor captureScreenshotWithDescription but for me "captureScreenshotWithDescription" is not coming can you please suggest what can i do now?

Comment: I tried this 
    KIFSystemTestActor *testActor = [[KIFSystemTestActor alloc] init];
    [testActor captureScreenshotWithDescription:@"screenshot11"]; but its giving error failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]"